# Is the logic $\mathsf{wK4}$ plus Lob's rule the same as $\mathsf{GL}$?

Tags: propositional-calculus, modal-logic

Let $\mathsf{wK4}$ be the logic of weak transitive frames and $\mathsf{GL}$ be the provability logic.

It is well-known that one can define $\mathsf{GL}$ as $\mathsf{K4}$ (the logic of transitive frames) plus Lob's rule: from $\Box A \rightarrow A$ deduce $A$.

But what about $\mathsf{wK4}$ plus Lob's rule? It seems to me that it is not equal to $\mathsf{GL}$. But I cannot come up with a proper explanation.

Any hints or suggestions?

P.S. I am familiar with the Kripke and topological semantics of $\mathsf{wK4}$ and $\mathsf{GL}$.